# How do I stop the annoying prompts to log into Microsoft Account

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I havent signed into my Microsoft Account for years.  Since I was about to change my motherboard, I got it working, in case I needed it.

After changing the motherboard, Windows was deactivated.  Even though my **current** account had admin priviledges, it gave a blank screen during the process of activating it.

So I tried the **Administrator** account.  After supplying the username and password for the MS account, it wanted the password for the local account. I have not used it in years as I use a pin.

So I switched to another admin account I have (for emergencies).  Same deal, I cant remember the password.  Stupidly from MS's point of view, I reset the password with a command prompt command. And I was able to activate Windows.

### But Now

This account is associated with a windows account.  I dont use it except in emergencies.  But it is harassing me on my mobile that I have to log into my Microsoft Account on either my desktop or laptop!  Its doing this multiple times a day.  I presume this is because of **Windows Link** app.

**How can I stop this annoying prompt ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had accepted @Harrymc's answer as I had thought that it worked.  But for some reason it did not.  What worked for me was to sign into all my accounts and disable Microsoft login.

- Go to Start Menu
- From the icon list on the left, select the Person (User Account)
- Right Click
- Select **Change Account Settings**
- Select **Sign in with local account instead**
- It will ask for the Microsoft account password
- Ensure that you know your local account password !!

Answer (score 9):

Try this :

- Run the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to :
  *Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings >
  Local Polices > Security Options*
- Double-click "Accounts: Block Microsoft accounts"
- Select "Users can't add or log on with Microsoft accounts"
- Click OK
- Reboot.

This requires you to always be able to log in with using only local accounts.
If you will need in the future to log in to your Microsoft account,
you will need to disable this policy.

Comment: Its partly worked.  I dont get the beeping on the mobile anymore, but there is still a silent notification.  Maybe there is a way to disassociate an account from Microsoft.

Comment: This policy seems to do nothing, at least on Windows 10 22H2.